# How to control the word 'Theorem' itself in mdframed

Tags: mdframed

In an `mdframed` theorem environment you get the word 'Theorem' appearing at the top of the frame. How can one control the colour and/or font of the word 'Theorem' in `mdframed`? Say, I want it to be red and in `\ttfamily` style?

Comment: Could you provides us with your current `\newmdtheoremenv` definition?

Answer (score 2):

So I am using the very first example from the manual:

```
\newmdtheoremenv%
[
outerlinewidth = 0.1,%
roundcorner = 10pt, %
leftmargin= 40, %
rightmargin=40,%
shadow = true,% 
backgroundcolor= yellow!20,%
innertopmargin=0.5ex,%
splittopskip= \topskip,% 
ntheorem = true,%
frametitlefont = {\twriter\color{red}},%has no effect
subtitlefont ={\twriter} % has no effect
]
{dvthm}{Theorem}[equation]
```

The last two entries for frametitlefont and subtitlefont I include just to demonstrate my attempt at doing something to control the title. But nothing happens. Moreover, as far as I understood it these option will only control the so called optional title you can specify. The actual 'Theorem' word - I see no attribute that controls it.

The only option I see is that in the last part

```
\newmdtheoremenv[...]{dvthm}{Theorem}[equation]
```

At the very end of the environment one can replace the word 'Theorem' there with the style one likes. But surely this is too crude and not systematic.

Comment: and if you do as I suggest then you can control the word 'Theorem' but not the number of the environment which will remain with the original settings.

Comment: Don't add edits as answer, edit your question. Also put code in the code environment by selecting them and then click on the `{}`.  And I would use tcolorbox instead of mdframed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think those are not the same Pauls (the OP and the answer guy)... I was pretty confused as well but at least the profiles are different ones.

Comment: @ALL: sorry guys it is the same Paul. Simply when I tried to comment before I got denied saying I have to have reputation 50 to make a comment. When I tried to edit my question it said something similar. So I had to use the answer. Now for some reason I can write a comment.

Comment: @Paul: You seem to have two profiles, flag a moderator so that they sort this out.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 1):

In case you decide to change to `tcolorbox` you could try following code.
It tries to mimic first example from `mdframed` documentation.

For `tcolorbox`, the title is formatted by `Theorem~number` where `Theorem` is the third parameter in `\newtcbtheorem` command. Font and color are fixed with options `coltitle` and `fonttitle`. The theorem name color and font are fixed with `description color` and `description font` options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
    mystyle/.style={theorem style=plain,
                        enhanced, 
                        colback=yellow!20, 
                        colframe=blue!70!black, 
                   fonttitle=\ttfamily\upshape,
                   fontupper=\itshape,  
                        coltitle=green!70!black,    
                        description color=red,
                        description font=\sffamily\bfseries
                   },
}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{myTheorem}{Theorem}{mystyle}{theo}

\begin{document}

\section{Theorems}

\begin{myTheorem}{Pythagorean theorem}{Pythagoras}
In any right triangle, the area
of the square whose side is the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the areas
of the squares whose sides are the two legs.
\[a^2 + b^2 = c^2\]
\end{myTheorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]